# configure Hibernate to use a renamed persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

We have to rename persistence.xml to fool WebSphere 7 not to use its built-in OpenJPA.

It is pretty easy to do when you use Spring, you just instruct its entity manager factory to use another location for persistence.xml:

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="META-INF/persistence-xxx.xml"/>
```

But now we want to use plain Hibernate/JPA without Spring, and couldn't find any way to specify the alternate persistence.xml location.

JPA2 spec doesn't say anything about it...

Any clues? Is it possible to instruct Hibernate to use a renamed persistence.xml?

======

It appears that it is NOT POSSIBLE to make Hibernate read a renamed persistence.xml file.
And not necessary in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not possible to change the location of the `persistence.xml` file.

Also take a look at this document: [Alternate JPA Providers in WebSphere Application Server](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/tejb_configpp.html), it seems like you should be able to use Hibernate as JPA provider by specifying it in the `persistence.xml` file, and embedding the required jars in your application.

Make sure your persistence.xml is specifying Hibernate as JPA provider:

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="myapp">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
```

You should also be able to achieve this by creating a shared library and using it to  configure WebSphere to use an alternative persistence provider. 
Here you can find how to do it: [Configuring the Java Persistence API (JPA) default persistence provider](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.zseries.doc/info/zseries/ae/tejb_configpp.html)

**EDIT** 
Given the information in the comments in this answer, it seems the problem can be solved by adding these properties in `persistence.xml`, as indicated in this post [Websphere EntityManagerFactory creation problem](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=234032):

```
<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
value="org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup" />

<property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class"
value="org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory" />
```

This same information is also provided in the  Alternate JPA Providers in WebSphere Application Server document.

Comment: Thanks! That will involve additional installation procedures each time we install the application, writing an instruction etc. But if we don't find some other way and this is the only option - we'll have to do that...

Comment: Also, take a look at this document: [Alternate JPA Providers in WebSphere Application Server](http:///www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/wikis/form/anonymous/api/library/53181ccd-bcd4-431f-b968-0b5f6d46d652/document/192a432b-28bb-4080-b037-345e5d83da76/attachment/61e74f67-1d60-4120-ba25-ad7264c9f4f6/media/AlternateJPAProviders_TestReport.pdf). Looks like you should be able to use hibernate by specifying the `provider` in persistence.xml and by embedding the required jars in your application. See my edit on the answer.

Comment: Xavi, we did specify provider... but it just resulted in `The server cannot create an EntityManagerFactory factory for the xxx persistent unit from the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence provider in jar:file:/C:/IBM/WebSphere/wp_profile/installedApps/XXX/xxx-ear.ear/xxx-ejb.jar!/ module.` It could be a separate issue of course...

Comment: Thanks!!! I just couldn't think that the solution would be so _strange_... I would actually prefer to rename persistence xml rather than making it WebSphere aware

Answer (score 0):

the persistence.xml should exist in a META-INF directory, usually packaged alongside a jar file that contains your entity classes. What I do is I have the entity clases in a seperate project under eclipse, with a META-INF directory that contains the persistence.xml, package this a jar file, and include it in the applications project dependencies (ie. WEB-INF/lib), or, deploy it straight to the app server.